# How to create new ID numbers into existing column when using pivot_longer

Tags: pivot, tidyverse

I'm trying to restructure my data in a long format using pivot_longer in tidyverse. I have an ID column for each entry (row) but as I am creating a longer format new rows will be added and I want to create a new ID number for these that will be added to the existing ID column.

In a simplified version my data looks like this:

| ID | Census | Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | t1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | t1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | t2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | t2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | t2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

What I want it to look like after pivot long is:

| ID | Census | Tab_ID | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | t1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2001 | t1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | t1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1002 | t1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2002 | t1 | 3 | 1 |

I manage to pivot it but don't know how to add new ID numbers for the new rows that are created due to the pivot.

My script looks like this:

long <- df %>%
pivot_longer(cols = 3:5, names_to = 'Tab_ID', names_prefix = "Tab", values_to = 'Score')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mutate()` to change your `ID` after `pivot_longer()`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
            Census = c("t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2"),
              Tab1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
              Tab2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
              Tab3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)


df |> pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID,Census),
                   names_to = "Tab_ID",
                   names_prefix = "Tab",
                   values_to = "score") |> 
  mutate(ID = ifelse(row_number(ID) %% 3 == 1, ID,
               ifelse(row_number(ID) %% 3 == 2, ID+1000, ID+2000)))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 18 × 4
      ID Census Tab_ID score
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <int>
 1     1 t1     1          1
 2  1001 t1     2          0
 3  2001 t1     3          1
 4     2 t1     1          1
 5  1002 t1     2          0
 6  2002 t1     3          1
 7     3 t1     1          0
 8  1003 t1     2          0
 9  2003 t1     3          0
10     4 t2     1          1
11  1004 t2     2          1
12  2004 t2     3          0
13     5 t2     1          1
14  1005 t2     2          1
15  2005 t2     3          0
16     6 t2     1          1
17  1006 t2     2          1
18  2006 t2     3          0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks YH Jang. I do not see how this solves my problem though. The ID number remains 1 1 1 2 2 2 etc, whereas I would like unique ID numbers for each row (with the first input remaining the old ID number, e.g.1, 2, 3, etc), but then the added rows having a new unique ID number (e.g., 1001, 1002, 1003). Any suggestions on how to create new unique values to the new rows that are created by the pivot?

Comment: @Saskia I just edited the answer. How about `mutate()` after `pivot_longer()`?

Comment: Ah nice, that's a clever way of overcoming that problem. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you like the answer, please accept it :)